# Creating a if filename is .png run loop, if .jpg ignore loop

Tags: python

I'm attempting to generate a word cloud in a specific image shape. JPGs don't need transformations; however PNGs do. I want to write a line that says if the image being loaded is a PNG run the transformation code, if its a JPG ignore the transformation code.

I'm not super familiar with python and coding, so I don't exactly know how it would be implemented, but my idea is it would look something like:

```
if  heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("filename.png")) 
    then #runs rest of transformation code 
if heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("filename.jpg"))
    then #runs rest of generation code
```

This is the actual code I'm running:

```
import os

from os import path
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS

#d=path.dirname(_file_) if "_file_" in locals() else os.getcwd()
os.chdir('C:/Users/Sams PC/Desktop/Word_Cloud_Scripts/Dmitrys Papers/Word_Cloud_Dmitry')
Document=open('Dmitry_all_lower.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')
text=Document.read()

heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("PCNA.png"))
heart_mask=heart_mask.reshape((heart_mask.shape[0],-1), order= 'F')
def transform_format(val):
    if val==0:
            return 255
    else:
            return val

transformed_heart_mask = np.ndarray((heart_mask.shape[0],heart_mask.shape[1]), np.int32)
print ('Transforming Image')
for i in range(len(heart_mask)):
    transformed_heart_mask[i]=list(map(transform_format, heart_mask[i]))

stopwords=set(STOPWORDS)
print ('Transformation Done')
stopwords.update(["will", "us","protein","residue", "interaction","residues","using","proteins"])
wc= WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords, background_color="white",max_words=1000, mask=heart_mask, contour_width=3, contour_color='black')
print ('Generating Word Cloud')

wc.generate(text)
```

The comment section has a character limit, so I can't properly post the entire modified code, so I'm making it here:

```
heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("nmr.jpg"))
split= str('nmr.jpg').rsplit('.')
extension=split[len(split)-1]
if extension == "png":
    heart_mask=heart_mask.reshape((heart_mask.shape[0],-1), order= 'F')
    def transform_format(val):
            if val==0:
                return 255
            else:
                return val
    transformed_heart_mask = np.ndarray((heart_mask.shape[0],heart_mask.shape[1]), np.int32)
    for i in range(len(heart_mask)):
            transformed_heart_mask[i]=list(map(transform_format, heart_mask[i]))
    else:
        continue
print(transformed_heart_mask)

stopwords=set(STOPWORDS)
print ('Transformation Done')
```

As stated, this gives the follow error:

```
SyntaxError: 'continue' not properly in loop
```

Furthermore, my transformed_heart_mask is no longer defined by putting it in that loop.

Fixed it, stupid mistake, didn't realize I was using a jpg file, so of course it wasn't running my mask transformation (hence why it wasn't defined). I also changed the continue to simply print (''), so it just doesn't run anything and skips the loop if its a jpg. Thank you!

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split from last `.` and take the latest part. This must give file's extension so if it equals `jpg` we are continuing.

```
splitted = str(filename.lower()).rsplit('.')
extension = splitted[len(x)-1]
if extension == "png":
    # do work
else:
    continue
```

Comment: I think I'm getting the idea here, but can't seem to get it work. Here is what I currently have:

```heart_mask=np.array(Image.open("nmr.jpg"))
split= str('nmr.jpg').rsplit('.')
extension=split[len(split)-1]
if extension == "png":
    heart_mask=heart_mask.reshape((heart_mask.shape[0],-1), order= 'F')
    def transform_format(val):....
    else:
        continue
stopwords=....```

So I understand split now means extension == whatever the filetype is (png or jpg), however I get the error that continue 'not properly in loop'. Furthermore, my transformed mask no longer is defined

Comment: Nevermind, made a dumb mistake and resolved it. I still was unable to fix the continue error, but I simply changed it to else: print (''), and this works in simply skipping the transformation loop if its a jpg, thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, i didn't see your comment question. You'r welcome :). If my answer helped you, you can mark it as an accepted answer.

Comment: I did, but it says votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are not publicly posted.

Comment: You tried to voted :). Users less than 15 reputation cannot vote. As a question asker, when a person answers your question well, you would 'accept' that answer. Do you see a tick mark under the vote symbol? You need to click it in order to accept an answer :) [you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Ah now I see. Sorry, a bit new to all of this.